# unusual traffic from your computer network google php curl

Tags: php, curl

I was trying to fetch data from google search. I used the below code

```
function get ( $url2 ){
$curl = curl_init($url2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agt);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $output;
}
$url2 = "https://www.google.com/search?output=toolbar&q=".str_replace(' ', '+', $qa);
$output = get($url2);
echo $output;
```

But its not displaying the page like below

[image]

Please somebody help me to solve this... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Automated Google search requests outside their API are block by Google. You script's request was (correctly) detected as an automated search request, so they responded with a reCAPTCHA to check if it was actually made by a human.

Google does this to prevent abuse, and to push people into using their [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) which they offer.

Comment: how to handle it without API

Comment: @AgungKahono The idea is that you can't... Google won't let you.

Comment: Is there any other solution